# Is it possible to count incorrect passcode attempts in iOS?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ipad, passwords

Is there any way to get some kind notification about incorrect passcode attempts? For example - when i try to unlock iPhone my App get notification about it.
Also i am interested in same function on OSX for incorrect password attempts.
Thanks.

Comment: Is the passcode for something in the iOS system itself or is it for something you have implemented such as a web service?

Comment: I mean iOS screen locking passcode. Not custom or web implemented.

Comment: No. There is no (public) API of any kind that would allow a 3rd party app to know anything about passcode attempts.

Comment: It is what i thinked! Ok then. Question is closed, thanks!